# Помогите разобраться с массивами

Tags: c#, массивы

Народ помогите. Не могу никак освоить массивы в C#. вот пытаюсь что-то сделать - всё без толку. Думал что при вводе мне покажет сколько символом я ввёл но в любом из случаев получаю 1. Что не так?

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string[] args){
        string [] array = new string[] {Console.ReadLine()}
        Console.WriteLine(array.Lenght);
        Console.Readkey();
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Почему код выводит 1

Comment: если ввожу больше символов

Comment: @AquaGF это в вопросе и нужно писать. про инициализацию массивов почитайте. если ты не задаешь длину изначально, то длина зависит от количества элементов, которые ты в массив добавляешь. {Console.ReadLine()} - это один элемент типа string. ПОэтому у тебя массив из одного элемента.

Comment: извините первый раз сюда пишу. А каким образом можно реализовать мысль? Что бы выводило количество элементов в введенном тексте.

Comment: @AquaGF  вы хотите количество символов? string str = Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine(str.Length);

Comment: О всё спасибо. Ещё раз извините за неформальность на форуме.

Comment: @AquaGF все ок с неформальностью, но стоит отредактировать вопрос и вставить код в виде кода, а не в виде картинки :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы вводите данные через `Console.Readline()`, консоль читает линию (ну, `ReadLine`, вы поняли), как одну строку, с указанием пробелов и вот этого всего.
Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] {Console.ReadLine().Split('X');} 
// separator examples: ' ', '/', '.' и т.д.
// Пример: "Roses aren’t red and Violets aren’t blue" с сепаратором ' ' (пробел)
// Поделит на [Roses|aren’t|red|and|Violets|aren’t|blue] - 7 эл.
```

> Где `X` - разделитель(separator) вашей строки.

Либо вы можете работать с массивом символов:

```
char[] myArray = new string[] {Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray;}
// здесь же, фразу: "They’re just a simulation, And so are you."
// поделит на 42 элемента, каждый из которых является символом. Включая пробелы и знаки препинания.
```

Это уже зависит от того, с чем вы хотите работать, при "освоении массивов".